# Finding relevant parts in XML document

Tags: import, string-manipulation, xml

My question is about a XML document and finding parts of strings.

```
test = Import["C:\\Users\\filename.xml", "XMLObject"]
```

This gives the following output:

```
XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]
   ["Version" -> "1.0", "Encoding" -> "UTF-8", "Standalone" -> "yes"]},
  XMLElement["file", {"name" -> "filename.xml"},
   {XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test1"},
     {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "3"},
       {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "AA-504771"}, {}],
        XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "BB-59362"}, {}],
        XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "CC-59362"}, {}]}]}],
    XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test2"},
     {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "2"},
       {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "AA-20210"}, {}],
        XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "3", "id" -> "BB-30211"}, {}]}]}],
    XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test3"},
     {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "2"},
       {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "AA-445227"}, {}],
        XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "BB-629609"}, {}]}]}],
    XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test4"},
     {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "2"},
       {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "AA-7799"}, {}],
        XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "BB-407682"}, {}]}]}]}], {}]
```

The XML has a fixed structure. I want the combination of the XML where
"write" -> "test1" and "id" -> "BB-59362"

The desired output is:

{test1, {AA-504771,BB-59362,CC-59362}},
test2, {AA-20210, BB-30211},
test3, {AA-445227,BB-629609},
test4, {AA-7799, BB-407682}}

I tried several syntaxes with, for example, XMLElement. The result in each case was output with XML. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: See also: [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22118/extract-attribute-data-from-an-xmlelement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a normal way to extract the data:-

```
xml = XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]
     ["Version" -> "1.0", "Encoding" -> "UTF-8", 
     "Standalone" -> "yes"]},
   XMLElement["file", {"name" -> "filename.xml"},
    {XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test1"},
      {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "3"},
        {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "AA-504771"}, {}],
         XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "BB-59362"}, {}],
         XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "CC-59362"}, {}]}]}],
     XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test2"},
      {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "2"},
        {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "AA-20210"}, {}],
         XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "3", "id" -> "BB-30211"}, {}]}]}],
     XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test3"},
      {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "2"},
        {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "AA-445227"}, {}],
         XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "BB-629609"}, {}]}]}],
     XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> "test4"},
      {XMLElement["relation", {"type" -> "co-synonyms", "freq" -> "2"},
        {XMLElement["lu", {"sense" -> "1", "id" -> "AA-7799"}, {}],
         XMLElement[
          "lu", {"sense" -> "2", "id" -> "BB-407682"}, {}]}]}]}],
   {}];

tekstcases = Cases[xml, XMLElement["tekst", __], \[Infinity]];

tests = Map[# /. XMLElement["tekst", {___, "write" -> x_}, ___] :> x &, tekstcases];

idcases = Cases[#, XMLElement["lu", __], \[Infinity]] & /@ tekstcases;

ids = Map[# /. XMLElement["lu", {___, "id" -> x_}, ___] :> x &, idcases];

Flatten[Transpose[{tests, ids}], 1]
```

> {test1, {AA-504771, BB-59362, CC-59362}, test2, {AA-20210,
>      BB-30211}, test3, {AA-445227, 
>     BB-629609}, test4, {AA-7799, BB-407682}}

Using replacements (`/.`) requires that every 'tekst' record has a 'write' and an 'id', otherwise `Cases` should be used.  But if the data is regularly structured replacements will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

In this case what you want is simple/regular enough that you can define the `XMLElement` etc. as functions that return what you want inside a `Block`:

```
Block[{XMLObject, XMLElement},
 XMLObject["Document"] = #2 &;
 XMLElement["tekst", {"write" -> t_}, data_] := {t, Sequence @@ data};
 XMLElement["lu", attr_, data_] := "id" /. attr;
 XMLElement[tag_, attr_, data_] := data;
 Flatten[test, 1]]
(*
  {"test1", {"AA-504771", "BB-59362", "CC-59362"},
   "test2", {"AA-20210",  "BB-30211"},
   "test3", {"AA-445227", "BB-629609"},
   "test4", {"AA-7799", "BB-407682"}}
*)
```

Omit the `Flatten` if you want the `"write"` paired with the `"id"`.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael E2 it took  me a while to figure out how this worked, but when I did I was extremely impressed with the elegance, simplicity and generality of this solution. +100

Answer (score 2):

The following can be used to extract the identifiers used in a given test case, which matches the "write" attribute of an individual `XMLElement`. Note that the attribute names "write" and "id" are hard-coded, which is not ideal.

```
GetIdentifiers[data_, test_String] := Module[{elem, attr},
  (*find test case*)
  elem = Cases[data, 
    XMLElement[___, {___, "write" -> test, ___}, ___], \[Infinity]];
  (*get selected xml attribute*)
  attr = Cases[elem, 
    XMLElement[___, {___, "id" -> attrib_, ___}, ___] :> 
     attrib, \[Infinity]];
  {test, attr}
  ]

GetIdentifiers[symbolicXML, "test1"]
```

> {"test1", {"AA-504771", "BB-59362", "CC-59362"}}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the example XML shown is representative, then we can exploit the fact the *write* and *id* attribute names are unambiguous within *tekst* elements:

```
Cases[test
, XMLElement["tekst", a_, c_] :> Sequence["write" /. a, Cases[c, ("id" -> i_) :> i, -1]]
, -1
]

(*
{ "test1", {"AA-504771", "BB-59362", "CC-59362"}, "test2", {"AA-20210", "BB-30211"},
  "test3", {"AA-445227", "BB-629609"}, "test4", {"AA-7799", "BB-407682"} }
*)
```

`Sequence` could be replaced with `List` or `Rule` if it is preferable to keep the *write* / *id* groups together.  For example, using `Rule`:

```
Cases[test
, XMLElement["tekst", a_, c_] :> Rule["write" /. a, Cases[c, ("id" -> i_) :> i, -1]]
, -1
]

(*
{ "test1"->{"AA-504771", "BB-59362", "CC-59362"}, "test2"->{"AA-20210", "BB-30211"},
  "test3"->{"AA-445227", "BB-629609"}, "test4"->{"AA-7799", "BB-407682"} }
*)
```