# Convert `FullForm` to XML Structure and back

Tags: functions, xml

How might I create a function that converts between `FullForm` and a XML structuce?

Ultimately I'm ideally looking to use CSS and JS to edited the XML structure.

For example using jquery I might do something like `$('Times Power')`.

Ideally I'm looking for the following code to export the following xml.

```
Times[a, Rational[1, -2], "test"]
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Times>
  <Symbol>a</Symbol>
  <Rational>
   <Integer>1</Integer>
   <Integer>-2</Integer>
  </Rational>
  <String>test</String>
</Times>
```

Comment: Would `TreeForm` be somewhat in the ballpark? Consider also that `TreeForm` takes the same options as `TreePlot`, so it may be reasonably customizable.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  If you don't think this is a good idea feel free to downvote.  I'm most interested in trying to use Unix tools after the conversion has taken place.

Comment: I don't have anything against the idea. I guess I could use some help in understanding what you are trying to achieve specifically after producing the structure. Honestly it doesn't help that I can't think of any reasonable meaning for your sample input `("test") / z`. Maybe you could expand on what you want to do with this "folder structure form".

Comment: @MarcoB I would like to try and use Unix tools to mv files around.  Do you understand the example above and how it relates to `Times["test", Power[z, -1]]`?  I can''t tell if you misunderstand the example or just don't get the intent of converting it to a directory structure.

Comment: I think I understand the relationship between the expression and its `FullForm`. I apologize but, as you said, I don't think I grasp your *intent* at all. Is "test" the name of a file? What is the role of `z`?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes it is a name of a file.  It's a simple expression to show an example.  "test" would be a file.  I think it is a little more clear now.

Comment: @MarcoB I've changed the question to involve HTML.  I think the functionality is better fit for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you aware of MathML? It uses different tags but in its content variant its structure comes close to what you want. AND it is an official standard, so there are chances that you'll find information and libraries which help you to do what you want to do with CSS and JS. Mathematica can export to (content) MathML: `Export[expr,"MathML","Content" -> True, "Presentation" -> False]`.

Comment: @AlbertRetey +1 it's not much better then XML but it is a little better.  It still isn't ideal for selecting with CSS selectors though.  Css Selectors are the problem `Symbol:contains('Times')` works for a selector with one depth but doesn't work if their nested like you have above. Some of it isn't bad though because technically there really isn't a much better way to do it.

Comment: @William: sorry, I'm also not fluid concerning CSS selectors but am somewhat surprised that they are so limited. I think the depth problem is hardly to avoid in general: mathematical expressions can have arbitrary depth, so you probably will face similar problems with other approaches anyway, won't you? I also just realized that I meant to use `ExportString` not `Export`, but that you probably already found yourself. Sorry if this wasn't terrible helpful, but knowing about MathML is probably a good thing nevertheless :-). I hope you'll find a solution that works for you...

Comment: I see that you have made a flurry of edits to this question.  That suggests to me perhaps you did not think it through completely before posting.  Are you certain that the present version clearly describes what you wish to ask?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm happy to open a new a question instead next time, but I think the similarities in the question(& the impracticality of the 1st question) merited an edit.  Yes I didn't think it through completed, but give me a second to update the example and it is done with the edits.

Comment: Related http://jsfiddle.net/nunr4dck/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can understand this latter version of the question better. Unfortunately though I don't speak jquery, so I don't really understand your example, therefore I will leave the applications to you, and limit this answer to getting an XML form of a *Mathematica* expression.

As it happens, achieving something along those lines is pretty simple, since `Export` handles XML natively.

For instance, let's have a very simple expression such as `x / y`, whose `FullForm` nevertheless is different from its `InputForm`, since you are concentrating on `FullForm`s in your question:

```
FullForm[x/y]
(* Out: Times[x,Power[y,-1]] *)
```

We can generate an XML representation of this expression as follows:

```
xmlstring = ExportString[x/y, "XML"]

(* Out: 
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE Expression SYSTEM 'http://www.wolfram.com/XML/notebookml1.dtd'>
<Expression xmlns:mathematica='http://www.wolfram.com/XML/'
    xmlns='http://www.wolfram.com/XML/'>
  <Function>
    <Symbol>Times</Symbol>
    <Symbol>x</Symbol>
    <Function>
      <Symbol>Power</Symbol>
      <Symbol>y</Symbol>
      <Number>-1</Number>
    </Function>
  </Function>
</Expression>
*)
```

You will notice that this is already an explicit representation of the `FullForm` of the input expression.

---

If you would like to **carry out further modifications** to the XML structure in *Mathematica*, you can also import the structure as `XMLObject`s:

```
ImportString[xmlstring, "XML"]
```

> XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0"], 
>     XMLObject["Doctype"]["Expression", 
>      "System" -> "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/notebookml1.dtd"]}, 
>    XMLElement[
>     "Expression", {{"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "mathematica"} -> 
>       "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/", {"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", 
>        "xmlns"} -> "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/"}, {XMLElement[
>       "Function", {}, {XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"Times"}], 
>        XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"x"}], 
>        XMLElement[
>         "Function", {}, {XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"Power"}], 
>          XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"y"}], 
>          XMLElement["Number", {}, {"-1"}]}]}]}], {}, "Valid" -> True]

---

If you'd like to have a ***Mathematica* expression back from the XML version**, you can also do that by importing it as "ExpressionML" format:

```
ImportString[xmlstring, "ExpressionML"]
(* Out: x/y *)
```

Comment: +1 but I'm thinking more of the form `<Times>x<Power>y</Power><Power>1</Power></Times>`.  The current form would be terrible to interact with jQuery.

Comment: hmm.. Wouldn't jQuery be able to handle well-formed XML? It would seem that [`jQuery.parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) might be able to help with that, at least from my reading of its specs.

Comment: Yes but that isn't very well formatted IMO.  It's a good answer but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Css Selectors are the problem `Symbol:contains('Times')` works for a selector with one depth but doesn't work if their nested like you have above.  `<Number>-1</Number>` isn't bad though because technically there really isn't a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Combining Michael E2's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63381/finding-relevant-parts-in-xml-document) to another question, that redefines XMLElement, and MarcoB's answer above, here is another approach.

To get the Wolfram expression of the messy XML that will recreate the original Wolfram expression (there is probably a better way):

```
ImportString[ExportString[Hold[Times[a, Rational[1, -2], "test"]], "XML"], "XML"]
```

This results in:

```
XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0"], 
  XMLObject["Doctype"]["Expression", 
   "System" -> "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/notebookml1.dtd"]}, 
 XMLElement[
  "Expression", {{"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "mathematica"} -> 
    "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/", {"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", 
     "xmlns"} -> "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/"}, {XMLElement[
    "Function", {}, {XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"Hold"}], 
     XMLElement[
      "Function", {}, {XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"Times"}], 
       XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"a"}], 
       XMLElement[
        "Function", {}, {XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"Rational"}], 
         XMLElement["Number", {}, {"1"}], 
         XMLElement["Number", {}, {"-2"}]}], 
       XMLElement["String", {}, {"test"}]}]}]}], {}, "Valid" -> True]
```

Here is a Block that redefines XMLElement to clean up the Wolfram XML, by taking out the Expression, the Hold, and the Functions, and changing Number to Integer. (The XML expression just sits at the bottom - no function call needed):

```
x1 = Block[{ XMLElement, symbolName},
   (* use block to temporarily redefine XMLElement *)
   symbolName[element : XMLElement["Symbol", attributes_, children_List]] :=
    First[children];
   XMLElement["Expression", attributes_, {child_}] := child;
   XMLElement["Function", attributes_, children_List] :=
    Module[{name},
     name = symbolName[First[children]];
     XMLElement[name, attributes, Rest[children]]];
   XMLElement["Hold", attributes_, {child_}] := child;
   XMLElement["Number", attributes_, {child_}] :=
    Module[{number, name},
     number = Interpreter["Number"][child];
     name = ToString@Head@number;
     XMLElement[name, attributes, child]];
   ImportString[
    ExportString[Hold[Times[a, Rational[1, -2], "test"]], "XML"], 
    "XML"]
   ];
```

Wolfram complains about bad XML, but still returns:

```
XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0"], 
  XMLObject["Doctype"]["Expression", 
   "System" -> "http://www.wolfram.com/XML/notebookml1.dtd"]}, 
 XMLElement[
  "Times", {}, {XMLElement["Symbol", {}, {"a"}], 
   XMLElement[
    "Rational", {}, {XMLElement["Integer", {}, {"1"}], 
     XMLElement["Integer", {}, {"-2"}]}], 
   XMLElement["String", {}, {"test"}]}], {}, "Valid" -> False]
```

To make it readable, here is an indenting print engine:

```
(* indenting print engine *)
Remove[new, contents, cr, tab, inc, dec, in, open, close, string, 
  indent, initial, pp];
initial = "";
string = initial;
indent = 0;

(* always return the symbol, so can chain *)
pp[new] := Module[{}, string = initial; indent = 0; pp];
pp[contents] := string;
pp[s_String] := Module[{x}, string = string <> s; pp];
pp[cr] := pp["\n"];
pp[tab] := pp["\t"];
(* inc increases indent; dec decreases indent *)
pp[inc] := Module[{}, indent = indent + 1; pp];
pp[dec] := Module[{}, indent = Max[indent - 1, 0]; pp];
(* in makes the indent *)
pp[in] := If[indent > 0, pp[StringRepeat["\t", indent]], pp]

(* add XML to the engine *)
initial = "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n";
pp[open, name_String] := pp["<"][name][">"]
pp[close, name_String] := pp["</"][name][">"]
pp[x : XMLObject["Document"][a_, body_, rest__]] := pp[body];
pp[x : XMLElement[name_String, attributes_, {text_String}]] := 
 Module[{}, pp[open, name][text][close, name]]
pp[x : XMLElement[name_String, attributes_, children_List]] := 
 Module[{},
  pp[open, name][inc];
  Scan[(pp[cr][in][#]) &, children];
  pp[dec][cr][in][close, name]]
```

To print x1:

```
pp[new][x1][contents]
```

Which results in:

```
"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Times>
    <Symbol>a</Symbol>
    <Rational>
        <Integer>1</Integer>
        <Integer>-2</Integer>
    </Rational>
    <String>test</String>
</Times>"
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work fairly close.

```
t = ToBoxes[FullForm@ReleaseHold@ReplaceAll[
       Hold["test"/a], {
        x_String :> String[x],
        x_Real :> Real[x],
        x_Integer :> Integer[x]
        }
       ]][[1, 1]];
ReplaceRepeated[t,
 {
  RowBox[{b_String, "[", x___String, "]"}] :> 
   StringJoin[{"<", b, ">", x, "</", b, ">"}],
  RowBox[{b___String}] :> StringJoin[{b}],
  "," :> ""
  }
 ]

 > "<Times><Power>a<Integer>-1</Integer></Power><String>\"test\"</String>\
```

"

and converting back.

```
ReplaceRepeated[
 ImportString[
   "<Times><Power>a<Integer>-1</Integer></Power><String>\"test\"</\
String></Times>", "XML"][[2]], {
  XMLElement["Integer", {}, {x_String}] :> x,
  XMLElement["String", {}, {x_String}] :> x,
  XMLElement[x_String, {}, {y___String}] :> 
   StringJoin[x, "[", StringJoin@Riffle[{y}, ","], "]"]
  }
 ]
```